# Animate Scroll not happening

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

100 questions already around but still not able to find solution as to why my snippet fails

This is the jQuery i am using :

```
$("#readmore").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        $("#readmore_div").slideToggle('slow',function(){
            if($(this).is(':visible')){ //if div is visible
                link.html('<b>Close</b>'),//Change text & scroll 
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $("#readmore_div").offset().Top});
            }else{ //Revert back original text
                link.html('<b>Read More</b>');
            }
        });
    });
```

text through `html()` is changing fine, but `animate` is not scrolling the page to `#readmore_div`

Can any one point out the error please!

Comment: Can you post your html as well? Or create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replaced `Top` with `top` in your code.

Try this:

```
$("#readmore").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        $("#readmore_div").slideToggle('slow',function(){
            if($(this).is(':visible')){ //if div is visible
                link.html('<b>Close</b>'),//Change text & scroll 
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : $("#readmore_div").offset().top});
            }else{ //Revert back original text
                link.html('<b>Read More</b>');
            }
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QADbb/1

Current function changes the button's text to `Read More` and clicking it once again scrolls it to the `#readmore_div`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#errors').offset().top},'slow');
```